# How to delete a particular node from xml document?

Tags: c#, xml

I have below xml structure. I want delete a complete node `<ColumnValues>USD</ColumnValues>`

```
<TableValue>
    <Columns>
        <ColumnName>Currency</ColumnName>
        <ColumnType>String</ColumnType>
        <ColumnValues>USD</ColumnValues>
        <ColumnValues>USD</ColumnValues>
    </Columns>
    <Columns>
        <ColumnName>Exchange</ColumnName>
        <ColumnType>String</ColumnType>
        <ColumnValues>US</ColumnValues>
        <ColumnValues>US</ColumnValues>
    </Columns>
    <Columns>
        <ColumnName>Ticker</ColumnName>
        <ColumnType>String</ColumnType>
        <ColumnValues>C</ColumnValues>
        <ColumnValues>AAPL</ColumnValues>
    </Columns>
</TableValue>
```

For this I am using below code -

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\CASInputRequest_WOELN_Var1.xml");
XmlNodeList NodeTradeType = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ColumnValues");
NodeTradeType[0].RemoveAll();
doc.Save(@"C:\CASInputRequest_WOELN_Var1.xml");
```

but its not removing complete node. The output is coming like this -

```
<TableValue>
    <Columns>
        <ColumnName>Currency</ColumnName>
        <ColumnType>String</ColumnType>
        <ColumnValues>
        </ColumnValues>
        <ColumnValues>USD</ColumnValues>
    </Columns>
    <Columns>
        <ColumnName>Exchange</ColumnName>
        <ColumnType>String</ColumnType>
        <ColumnValues>US</ColumnValues>
        <ColumnValues>US</ColumnValues>
    </Columns>
    <Columns>
        <ColumnName>Ticker</ColumnName>
        <ColumnType>String</ColumnType>
        <ColumnValues>C</ColumnValues>
        <ColumnValues>AAPL</ColumnValues>
    </Columns>
</TableValue>
```

Please suggest, how to completely delete a particular node from xml?

Comment: Are you able to use LINQ to XML, by the way? That generally makes XML more pleasant to deal with.

Comment: Relevant docs: [MSDN – `System.Xml.XmlNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx)

Answer (score 14):

Odd as is sounds, there's no method on `XmlNode` which will remove that node from the document. You need to ask the node's parent to remove the node:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\CASInputRequest_WOELN_Var1.xml");
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ColumnValues");
XmlNode node = nodes[0];
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
doc.Save(@"C:\CASInputRequest_WOELN_Var1.xml");
```

If you can use LINQ to XML life will be easier though. For example, to remove all `ColumnValues` nodes you'd just use:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\CASInputRequest_WOELN_Var1.xml");
doc.Descendants("ColumnValues").Remove();
doc.Save(@"C:\CASInputRequest_WOELN_Var1.xml");
```

Or just the first one:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\CASInputRequest_WOELN_Var1.xml");
doc.Descendants("ColumnValues").First().Remove();
doc.Save(@"C:\CASInputRequest_WOELN_Var1.xml");
```

Comment: @ilansch: Because it would be more sensible for there to be a `Remove` operation on `XmlNode` which would remove itself from the document - just as there is in LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void RemovePendingMessage(String message, String AdapterType, Configuration.Adapter xmlAdapterConfiguration, String traceSchedulerName, Int64 CorrelationID)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlNode docNode = null;
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                String date = String.Empty;
                string strValue = string.Empty;
                if (File.Exists(@"C:\Temp\UnsendMessages.xml"))
                {
                    xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\Temp\UnsendMessages.xml");
                    XmlNode Unsendmessages = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
                    XPathNavigator navigator = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
                    xdoc.LoadXml(message);                    

                    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(message)))
                    {
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("Adapter");
                        reader.MoveToContent();
                        strValue = reader.GetAttribute("timestamp");                         
                    }

                    if (strValue != null)
                    {
                        docNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Adapter[@timestamp='" + strValue.ToString() +"' and @type='" + AdapterType.ToString() + "']");
                        docNode.RemoveAll();                     
                    }
                 xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\Temp\UnsendMessages.xml");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
-------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Unsendmessages>
  <Adapter>
  </Adapter>
  <Adapter type="XMLAdapter" timestamp="2014-10-15 16:48:02Z">
    <Resendmessage>
      <WMRP_ORDERS>
        <ORDERSCONTRACTNO>C0017</ORDERSCONTRACTNO>
        <ORDERS_STATUSID>17</ORDERS_STATUSID>
        <ORDERSDATERECEIVED>9/2/2014 12:00:00 AM</ORDERSDATERECEIVED>
        <ORDERS_BT_ORDER_NO>O0017</ORDERS_BT_ORDER_NO>
        <ORDERS_REGION_CODE>17</ORDERS_REGION_CODE>
        <ORDERSSCHEDULEDSTARTDATE>9/2/2014 12:00:00 AM</ORDERSSCHEDULEDSTARTDATE>
        <ORDERSSCHEDULEDENDDATE>9/10/2014 12:00:00 AM</ORDERSSCHEDULEDENDDATE>
      </WMRP_ORDERS>
    </Resendmessage>
  </Adapter>
  <Adapter type="XMLAdapter" timestamp="2014-10-15 16:47:32Z">
    <Resendmessage>
      <WMRP_ORDERS>
        <ORDERSCONTRACTNO>C0016</ORDERSCONTRACTNO>
        <ORDERS_STATUSID>16</ORDERS_STATUSID>
        <ORDERSDATERECEIVED>9/2/2014 12:00:00 AM</ORDERSDATERECEIVED>
        <ORDERS_BT_ORDER_NO>O0016</ORDERS_BT_ORDER_NO>
        <ORDERS_REGION_CODE>16</ORDERS_REGION_CODE>
        <ORDERSSCHEDULEDSTARTDATE>9/2/2014 12:00:00 AM</ORDERSSCHEDULEDSTARTDATE>
        <ORDERSSCHEDULEDENDDATE>9/10/2014 12:00:00 AM</ORDERSSCHEDULEDENDDATE>
      </WMRP_ORDERS>
    </Resendmessage>
  </Adapter>
  <Adapter type="XMLAdapter" timestamp="2014-10-15 16:46:58Z">
    <Resendmessage>
      <WMRP_ORDERS>
        <ORDERSCONTRACTNO>C0017</ORDERSCONTRACTNO>
        <ORDERS_STATUSID>17</ORDERS_STATUSID>
        <ORDERSDATERECEIVED>9/2/2014 12:00:00 AM</ORDERSDATERECEIVED>
        <ORDERS_BT_ORDER_NO>O0017</ORDERS_BT_ORDER_NO>
        <ORDERS_REGION_CODE>17</ORDERS_REGION_CODE>
        <ORDERSSCHEDULEDSTARTDATE>9/2/2014 12:00:00 AM</ORDERSSCHEDULEDSTARTDATE>
        <ORDERSSCHEDULEDENDDATE>9/10/2014 12:00:00 AM</ORDERSSCHEDULEDENDDATE>
      </WMRP_ORDERS>
    </Resendmessage>
  </Adapter>
  <Adapter type="XMLAdapter" timestamp="2014-10-15 16:46:25Z">
    <Resendmessage>
      <WMRP_ORDERS>
        <ORDERSCONTRACTNO>C0016</ORDERSCONTRACTNO>
        <ORDERS_STATUSID>16</ORDERS_STATUSID>
        <ORDERSDATERECEIVED>9/2/2014 12:00:00 AM</ORDERSDATERECEIVED>
        <ORDERS_BT_ORDER_NO>O0016</ORDERS_BT_ORDER_NO>
        <ORDERS_REGION_CODE>16</ORDERS_REGION_CODE>
        <ORDERSSCHEDULEDSTARTDATE>9/2/2014 12:00:00 AM</ORDERSSCHEDULEDSTARTDATE>
        <ORDERSSCHEDULEDENDDATE>9/10/2014 12:00:00 AM</ORDERSSCHEDULEDENDDATE>
      </WMRP_ORDERS>
    </Resendmessage>
  </Adapter>
  <Adapter>
  </Adapter>
</Unsendmessages>
```